# Node TS, Build Generation Failed for Google Cloud Run, Giving Error Type 'IsTuple' not generic

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-run

I have Node ts Project and it is deployed on cloud run but while creating build it is giving below error.

```
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(41,54): error TS2315: Type 'IsTuple' is not generic.
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(53,6): error TS2456: Type alias 'IsTuple' circularly references itself.
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(53,65): error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type.
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(53,84): error TS2315: Type 'IsTuple' is not generic.
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(96,5): error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(131,5): error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
node_modules/@types/prettier/index.d.ts(165,5): error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I just updated the typescript version.

Comment: This should be a comment and not separate answer, you will be able to add comments after gaining reputations on platform.

Comment: I have installed typescript 4.6.4 but still same issue. @Mehdi All can you please tell the version you have installed?

Comment: @Sagar Darekar okay, I got it. 

btw I installed the version : v4.6.1-rc
and the prettier version is : v2.6.0